# Anonymous Authentication in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, ms-wopi

I have deployed a .NET core website on the IIS, the website that I deploy uses the WOPI service, and I can from my website edit word documents using Microsoft word (Word desktop),
when the IIS website redirects me to Microsoft word it opens the Microsoft word and requests a user name and password, how can I disable this authentication?
I think I should add an anonymous authentication custom header in the IIS, if yes how can I add this custom header and should I add it in the HTTP response headers and what's its value?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled `Basic Authentication` in IIS? If yes, you need to disable `Basic Authentication` in the `Authentication` module and only enable `Anonymous Authentication`.

Comment: Thank you @JennyDai, Only the Anonymous Authentication is enabled in the IIS, but still the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have the `authentication mode` configured in the ASP.NET `Web.config` file, you can check this in your code.